# how to view a directory's permission

Tags: shell, permissions, directory

What is the command with which you can directly view the permission bits of a directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a couple ways. `stat` is used to show information about files and directories, so it's probably the best way. It takes a format parameter to control what it outputs; `%a` will show the octal values for the permissions, while `%A` will show the human-readable form:

```
$ stat -c %a /
755
$ stat -c %A /
drwxr-xr-x
$ stat -c %a /tmp
1777
$ stat -c %A /tmp
drwxrwxrwt
```

---

Another (probably more common) way is to use `ls`. `-l` will make it use the long listing format (whose first entry is the human-readable form of the permissions), and `-d` will make it show the entry for the specified directory instead of its contents:

```
$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Apr 28 20:32 /
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 12K Sep 25 22:31 /tmp
```